# Android Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

A week ago, my emulator just run seamlessly without any problem, but now, everytime I started my Android Emulator from AVD manager, I am using Android Studio 3.1.2 and Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14. I got this error

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

and the emulator suddenly closed. It happens frequently and this can make me crazy and messed up my work.

**I have tried to delete and add a device profile, and Also I have tried clearing all the emulator cache. but still not works.**

If you know or ever encounter this problem, please help.

I try to use many device profile, but same thing happens. Here I used the device profile provided by Google which included google play in it.

[image]

I have no option for changing the RAM size or Graphic settings.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data of the emulator?

Comment: @JohnTheWalker yes, but nothing good happened.

Answer (score -1):

*Sorry i delete my answer before.*

I ever have the same problem, i just restart my Android Studio and create a new device in AVD MANAGER then I increased the RAM size of emulator and it works nicely.

I think it happens when you close emulator during building the App in to emulator.

**Or You Can Try This**

Tools -> AVD Manager -> (Edit this AVD) under Actions -> Emulated Performance (Graphics): select "Software GLES 2.0"

Comment: I have no option for that, I used the Google Device Profile which include google play in the emulator. for the Image, I will add it in my question.